# Magento 2 scandipwa child.isClassAccessorProperty is not a function

Tags: javascript, magento2.4, php-7.4, scandipwa

We are using Magento 2.4.3 version and php version is 7.4

Following that document - https://docs.scandipwa.com/getting-started-1/magento-integration

While running `BUILD_MODE=magento yarn start` command getting an issue of -

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/@scandipwa/scandipwa/src/util/Request/QueryDispatcher.ts
TypeError: /var/www/html/magento243_scandipwa/src/localmodules/my-app/node_modules/@scandipwa/scandipwa/src/util/Request/QueryDispatcher.ts: child.isClassAccessorProperty is not a function
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
```

please refer screenshot -
[image]